# How to implement erase() method in a C++ template container

Tags: c++, memory, vector

For a book exercise, I need to create a simple C++ container (mimicking that of std::vector) called Vec. However, I am having problems implementing a simple erase() method. My intention is to destroy the object within that index, then move back all elements after the index one spot down the list.

PS: I am new to C++ and don't know a whole lot about memory management in C++.

**Vec.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef GUARD_VEC_H
#define GUARD_VEC_H

#define WARNING D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define WARNING_ID 4996

#pragma message (WARNING)
#pragma warning (disable: WARNING_ID)

#define MAX(a , b) ((a > b) ? a : b) 
#define MIN(a , b) ((a < b) ? a : b)

#include <memory> //For: Allocator
#include <cstddef> //FOR: size_type


template<class T> class Vec {
    public: //interface
        typedef T* iterator;
        typedef const T* const_iterator;
        typedef size_t size_type;
        typedef T value_type;

        Vec() { create(); }
        explicit Vec(size_type n, const T& val = T()) { create(n, val); }
        Vec(const Vec& v) { create(v.begin(), v.end()); }

        Vec& operator = (const Vec&);
        ~Vec() { uncreate(); }
        T& operator[] (size_type i) { return data[i]; }
        const T& operator[] (size_type i) const { return data[i]; }

        void push_back(const T& t) {
            if (avail == limit)
                grow();
            unchecked_append(t);
        }

        void clear();
        bool erase(size_type i);

        size_type size() const { return avail - data; }

        iterator begin() { return data; }
        const_iterator begin() const { return data; }

        iterator end() { return avail; }
        const_iterator end() const { return avail;  }
    private: //implementation
        iterator data;
        iterator avail;
        iterator limit;

        std::allocator<T> alloc;

        void create();
        void create(size_type, const T&);
        void create(const_iterator, const_iterator);

        void uncreate();

        void grow();
        void unchecked_append(const T&);
};

template <class T> bool Vec<T>::erase(size_type i){
    //No, doesn't work at all
    if (i > size())
        return false;
    alloc.destroy(data+ i);
    return true;
    //Implement move-back

}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::clear(){
    uncreate(); //Destroys all objects and deallocates all addresses
    grow(); //Allocates addresses for next use.
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::create()
{
    data = avail = limit = 0;
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::create(size_type n, const T& val)
{
    data = alloc.allocate(n);
    limit = avail = data + n;
    std::uninitialized_fill(data, limit, val);
}

template <class T>
void Vec<T>::create(const_iterator i, const_iterator j){
    data = alloc.allocate(j - i);
    limit = avail = std::uninitialized_copy(i, j, data);
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::uncreate()
{
    if (data){
        iterator it = avail;
        while (it != data)
            alloc.destroy(--it);
        alloc.deallocate(data, limit - data);
    }
    data = limit = avail = 0;
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::grow()
{
    size_type new_size = MAX(2 * (limit - data), ptrdiff_t(1));
    iterator new_data = alloc.allocate(new_size);
    iterator new_avail = std::uninitialized_copy(data, avail, new_data);

    uncreate();

    data = new_data;
    avail = new_avail;
    limit = data + new_size;
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::unchecked_append(const T& val)
{
    alloc.construct(avail++, val);
}

template <class T> Vec<T>& Vec<T>::operator=(const Vec<T>& rhs)
{ //rhs = right hand side
    if (&rhs != this){
        uncreate();
        create(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
    }
    return *this;
}
#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Vec.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Windows.h"
#include <string>

int main(){
    Vec<double> vector;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        vector.push_back((double) i);
    }

    //Check Copy Constructor
    Vec<double> vector2 = vector;



    Vec<double> vector3;
    Vec<double> vector4;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        vector3.push_back((double)(i*2));
    }

    //Check Assignment Operator
    vector4 = vector3;



    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        std::cout << vector[i] << " " << vector2[i] << " " << " " << vector3[i] << " "
            << vector4[i] << std::endl;
    }

    //Check Erase Operator
    vector.erase(3);

    for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++){
        std::cout << vector[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

In main, "vector" is the object I am testing this on. It is initialized as numbers 0 through 9, and remains the same after vector.erase(3) is called;

Also, for an explanation on the iterators, data points to the beginning of the list (first element), avail points to where the initialized elements end, and limit points to where the uninitialized storage ends. data<=avail<=limit always.
So in the erase() method, I assume that data+i is what I need to destroy. After erased, avail-1.

Comment: Side issue: no need of a macro for `MAX`. Use `std::max` or write yourself a template function, but avoid using macros.

Comment: Compiler errors? Unexpected behavior? Mind to [explain more](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30143741/edit)?

Comment: No errors, only thing is vector is "unchanged"

Comment: Just because you destroy the object doesn't mean it disappears from the vector. Same reason you can still access `c` after `SomeClass c; c.~SomeClass();` (but don't do that).

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be homework, so this is not a complete answer.

I will however give hints.

There's a big problem with your initial guess at a solution. Once you have destroyed `data[i]`, that location is (or should be treated as) now unusable as an object of type `T`.  In particular, you cannot use `data[i] = data[i+1]` because the knowledge of the assignment operator may have been destroyed.

The standard remedy applies: Don't do that then.

You have figured out that you need to shift every element above element `i` down by one. So do that first, before you destroy anything. (That's a big hint.) When you're finished, there might well be something that needs to be destroyed (another big hint).

As an aside, the solution I hinted at above isn't very efficient. There are more efficient ways to do this in C++11.

Comment: Would this code be fine as another solution. It seems to do the job but not sure if there are any background problems. `avail = std::uninitialized_copy(data + index, avail, data + index-1);`

Answer (score -1):

here's how I got the erase function working:

```
template <class T> bool Vec<T>::erase(size_type i)
    {
        if (i > size())
            return false;
        //alloc.destroy(data + i); => not necessary, assuming T has a proper assignment operator defined

        for (int i = 0; i < size() - 1; i++)
            data[i] = data[i + 1];

        avail--; //decrease the size of the vector
        alloc.destroy(data + size());
        return true;
    }
```

You might want to look at [Difference between "destroy" "destructor" "deallocate" in std::allocator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667026/difference-between-destroy-destructor-deallocate-in-stdallocator) for an explanation of what allocator.destroy does.

Comment: This is not an answer. It invokes undefined behavior. Once destroyed, the statement `data[i] = data[i+1]` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: I didn't say anything about the copy constructor. I addressed your use of `data[i] = data[i+1]`. That is undefined behavior once `data[i]` is destroyed.

Comment: The updated solution still has some problems. (1) Using `data[i]=data[i+1]` is invalid (undefined behavior) for elements beyond the end of the usable part of the vector. Your loop goes too high. (2) If you fix this problem, this approach might leak resources. The last usable element of the vector (`data[avail-1]`) will have a carbon copy just above it.